# why skb buffer cannot be queued on two lists at the same time?

Tags: linux-kernel

why an skb cannot be queued at 2 list at the same time?

I have observed kernel panic while queuing skb at another list even if it is queued in at original list. Let me give an example where even though I have unlinked(but I haven't freed it) the skb from the orginal queue and while trying to queue the skb at the second list I get kernel panic.

```
skb_unlink(skb, &sk->sk_receive_queue);
 printk("%s %d", __func__, __LINE__);                                             
 skb_queue_tail(&sk->dup_queue, skb);  /*Error*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am able to provide a work around the same concept in kernel.As the skbs are not freed even though it unlinked from the first skbs, the memory assigned to it is not freed. The workaround is :

```
skb_unlink(skb, &sk->sk_receive_queue);
skb->destructor(skb);
skb_queue_tail(&sk->dup_queue, skb);
```

Later while freeing the skbs from the queue tail do :

```
skb->destructor = NULL; //As we have called it before 
sk_eat_skb(skb);
```